# Archive Mounter With Natilus

Tags: vlc, iso, totem, archive

I have one problem. I have many iso file and my iso file include many vido file ( Education vido, Personel video etc ... ) already. When time I use Archive Mounter then VLC medya player can't open vido file and give " VLC could not read the file. " eror and if I use Totem player open file but I am can't use Totem Player Time bar. If I copy vido file my master disk or usb disk then I can open this file vith VLC and I can use Totem player time bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

`sudo mount -o loop yourisofile.iso /media/isofile`

But first you need yo go to `/media` and create a folder (called `isofile` in the above example) where your iso will be mounted.

Comment: (Thanks to [N.N.](http://askubuntu.com/users/19490/n-n) for the original edit on which my slightly more extensive edit was based.)